# Install a basic CentOS VM on Fedora 19 with libvirt

Tags: networking, centos, virtual-machine, kvm, fedora

I would like to install a CentOS 6.5 virtual machine on my machine, only with command line tools and basic networking capabilities, i.e a way to have http and ssh connections between the host (Fedora 19) and the CentOS guest.

Being still quite noobish to the nix world, I experienced some trouble.

I first did an unsuccessful attempt to install virtualbox.

I then found this page on the fedorapoject.org's wiki titled: [Getting started with virtualization](http://fedoraproject.org//wiki/Getting_started_with_virtualization?rd=Virtualization_Quick_Start#Using_virtualization_on_Fedora).

I followed the instructions, installed the packages needed (libvirt ...), and enabled virtualization in my BIOS.
I installed my VM from the iso CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso
(with `virt-install --prompt` )

While the installation went all right, if I halt the VM I absolutely don't know how to restart it. The webpage I used apparently doesn't mention it, and having a look at virsh or virt-manager manual was not yielding help for me (but maybe because I don't know how to read it properly)

the `virsh list` doesn't show anything but an empty list.
i tried to find the machine I created using 
`find / -name name_of_vm_as_prompted_during_virt-install`
and found nothing

besides, while my guest is running, no network interface is there (except lo), despite the wiki stating that there should be a basic networking interface created by default that would allow me to have connection between guest and host.
However on my host I have

```
virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 8e:3d:7c:b3:44:bf  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
```

which, I guess, should be encouraging.

My knowledge on VM is quite limited and so is my understanding of networking.

My questions :

1. How to access my created but closed VM
2. How to set up the basic network capabilities
3. since I have 2 questions, should I split them into two separate threads ?

Comment: Well my comment could be an answer but a pretty heavy but though very powerfull solution is using Virtual Box (that has a cli capabilities) with php virtual box http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpvirtualbox/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am such a noobie that I can't get it started.

Comment: Installed Virtual box with `yum install VirtualBox`, and extracted it in my home folder. chmod u+x to the vboxinit. Got an error `/etc/default/virtualbox`does not exist. I `touch` so at list the exec script can go on, but nothing happened after that.

Comment: Well I can't make a chat now but maybe a bit later.

Comment: thanks! I feel so lost, a lot of docs focus on problems much more complex, nobody seems to just get stuck at this point :/

Comment: may worth notice : my first attempt to install and use VirtualBox was aborted due to some "kernel headers missing for your kernel" (I use 3.12.5)

Comment: In my 2nd comment, I of course meant "installed VirtualBox AND THEN downloaded phpVirtualBox and extracted it"

Comment: well you can first make virtualbox working by refering to http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox

Comment: Just install `virt-manager` and you can do what you want graphically. It works very similar to VirtualBox, we use it to manage several dozens of VMs on 5+ hosts.

Comment: Ok, a bit more explained on the CentOS wiki thanks. However it seems there is something wrong with the repos of virtual box for my Fedora 19... The repository config file doesn't work (404 not found when I try to use yum install or update or anything with the virtualbox repo). It looks like the repo file downloadable is not correct ? I gave a better look at it, in download.virtualbox.org (slash) virtualbox/rpm/fedora/ and there is a 19 folder, and when I look at it there are rpm named "fedora18" inside... I'll try to use them maybe ?

Comment: UPDATE : I had to manualy change the url in the repo and no more 404 error, ....virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/el/19/x86_64 , changed the *el* to *fedora* . Updating in progress, will continue this later

Comment: No, those RPMs are correct from Oracle. They are shipping the F18 builds for F19. That doesn't matter. http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/rpm/fedora/19/x86_64/

Comment: @slm Thank you for the infos. Since I already went through the steps for installing libvirt and virt-manager is already installed I will try this way. I'm still interested in knowing why my CLI approach with virt-install hasn't saved anything after the creation of my VM though.

Comment: I always suggest to newbie ppl to go w/ the GUI to start and then from the GUI you can see what command lines are getting constructed. That helps w/ getting up to speed with KVM more quickly. The trick w/ KVM is that it's an evolving technology, so much of the docs on the internet are just wrong. The GUI is the reference implementation so it has to stay in sync w/ all of the versions and can act like a Rosetta Stone.

Comment: If you want to go the VirtualBox route, the CLI command `VBoxManage` is your friend. The [documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) is pretty straightforward. I also activated [RPMFusion](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration) and installed VirtualBox from there. I'm on Fedora 20 + Gnome 3 and there's [Gnome Boxes](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Boxes?action=show&redirect=Boxes) although I'm not sure if it's KVM related.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally working like a charm
Answer to 1)
As suggested by slm, using `virt-manager` GUI kept trace of my created VM and I'm able to start it again.
Still interested in the way to do it via CLI tools though.

Answer to 2)

It was just a CentOS installation configuration misunderstanding, not related to libvirt (which had already done its job, see libvirt installation instructions about network, I don't remember where I got them but there are pretty straightforward for basic network config).

I just missed the "Configure network" button on CentOS installation screens. 
Or config manually, see for exemple : wiki.centos.org (slash) FAQ/CentOS6#head-b67e85d98f0e9f1b599358105c551632c6ff7c90

Comment: Just to complement the answer, if you skip che Configure Network wizard, you can still use networking. You have to edit the `/etc/sysconfig/networking` and enable `NETWORKING=yes` and edit the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` and enable `ONBOOT=yes`.